# Flash SWF local storage limitations

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, iframe, flash

We are creating an iframe in other websites pages and this iframe will have our JS.

From our iframe we need access to the browser's local storage and because this is cross-domain and also there are issues of http/https resources access we are thinking about using a small swf file that communicate with our JS code and will store all the data in the flash player resources and not the browser's.

My questions:
1) Any limitations on swf local storage size? 
2) When will that data be deleted - what is the expiration time of that data?
3) Is it only accessible from our domain? like native local storge is?

Also - do you have a better idea or other things we haven't considered?

Hope someone can help us.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Flash will ask user every time a site exceeds local storage limit of 10k, 100k, 1M, 10M. User can set up the limit every time. An option of unlimited storage is also available. User can set up different sizes for different sites. [Flash Player storage settings](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager07.html)
2) The data has no expiration time
3) The data is only accessible to the domain it was created by. It is stored in C:\users\%use-name%\AppData\Roaming\Macromedia\Flash Player\%site-name%.

You can find out more in [Adobe documentation](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=17_Networking_and_communications_6.html)

Answer (score -1):

Flash Global settings panel could help you better understand the functionality of online flash player.
http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager.html

This has multiple tabs for obvious reasons:
i) Global storage settings panel provides user with option of amount of disk-space to be utilised by any web site
ii) User can edit/change this setting for any specific web site using local storage settings.

iii) Flash local files are stored as temp files in browsers cache, and are cleared as per user settings of clearing temp files.

For all these Flash player provides an optimum default settings and user has to edit change his flash player settings. I doubt this can be taken done using some script at your website, as this shall be considered as user security breach.

http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/index.html this link shall provide you more insight on Flash Player Settings.